# node.js sending by request module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I need to send a lot of messages. I use external api and request module:

email.js

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function(subject, email){
    var message = ... ;
    var options = { 
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.emails.net.com/api/sendmail',
        form: {
            smtp_account: smtp,
            to: {},
            subject: subject,
            html: message,
            from: 'myapp@email.com',
            from_name: 'Myapp'
        },
        headers: {
            'Authorization': ' ... '
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) return true;
        return false;
    });
};
```

And in another place:

```
var sendEmail = require('../email');

...

for( ... ){
    if(sendEmail(subject, email)){
        //do something
    }
}
```

After success i want to do something but request return nothing. Is any way to check if post was success and do something in place where I require email module? I'm sending emails in loop and i must check one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var request = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var email = function () {
    return {
        send: function (subject, email) {
            var message = "test";
            var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.emails.net.com/api/sendmail',
                form: {
                    smtp_account: "smtp",
                    to: {},
                    subject: subject,
                    html: message,
                    from: 'myapp@email.com',
                    from_name: 'Myapp'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': ""
                }
            };
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                request(options, function (error, response) {

                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    }
};

module.exports = email();
```

And then you can consume this as below

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            console.log(i);
    email
        .send("test", "test@gmail.com")
        .then(function (status) {
            ///Do what ever u want to do
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

}
```